# From high school level analytic geometry to elementary real algebraic geometry (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, real-algebraic-geometry

I want to learn some real algebraic geometry. My background is high school mathematics.

Is there a textbook that provides a path from high school level analytic geometry to elementary real algebraic geometry?

I just want to have an idea what it's about, some of the problems it deals with, some nice elementary theorems, and so on, without delving deep into the subject (I guess).

Comment: I hope someone answers.  I also would like to know.

Comment: @user2661923: After many Google searches I found a review of a book that seems to be what we are looking for, "requiring only the rudiments of coordinate geometry and algebra" https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/real-algebraic-geometry by Vladimir I. Arnold. I'll try this one!